# "Transparency" of a template template argument (missing template argument)

Tags: c++, templates

To put it somewhat vaguely, from the snippet (tt.cc) below it seems to me as if the *template template* notion lacked some kind of a *"transparency"*. While I don't seem to fathom what other template argument should `A::f()` be provided (besides the template template one), I might as well be just missing some banality here.

```
template <class T>
class A {
public:
  template< template<class> class U >
  void f( int i ) {
    // ...
  }
};


template< class T, template<class> class U >
class B {
public:
  void f( int i ) {
    A<T> a;
    a.f<U>( i );
  }
};


int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

The error message it provides is:

```
g++ ./tt.cc -o tt
./tt.cc: In member function ‘void B<T, U>::f(int)’:
./tt.cc:17:10: error: missing template arguments before ‘>’ token
     a.f<U>( i );
          ^
Compilation exited abnormally with code 1
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I always pity the users who experience this because it's hard to google for it if you don't know the answer

Comment: @TemplateRex That's also been discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167123/question-closed-as-duplicate-could-not-be-found-by-the-op).

Comment: @0x499602D2 tnx, that's good to know

Comment: @TemplateRex it indeed was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the compiler interpreting the `>` token inside `f<U>` as the inequality operator. You need to add `.template` to let the compiler know you mean a template argument.

```
  void f( int i ) {
    A<T> a;
    a.template f<U>( i );
  }
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e68876d81edc89c).

See also [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/819272).

Comment: thank you! this operator misinterpretation is kind of an eye-opener... :-)

Comment: @calmity especially because the Visual C++ compiler lets you get away with it in many instances